# How to get the text value of a clicked link?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have matching text in different parts of a document. The first is a set of "tags" in a table like so:

```
<div id="my-div">
  <div><a href="#">tag 1</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">tag 2</a></div>
</div>
```

Then in several other parts of the document, I have a hidden element after the items I want to highlight when the matching link is selected like so:

```
<div class="hide-me">tag 1</div>
```

Then my click function is like this:

```
$('#my-div a').click(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text();
  console.log(txt);
});
```

The output is an empty string, but I’m not sure why.

Comment: I don't see any problem. [A sample](http://www.jsfiddle.net/reigel/WBNkB/)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

your code seems to be correct, try this one too.

```
$('#my-div a').click(function(e) {
  var txt = $(e.target).text();
  console.log(txt);
});
```

Comment: You're right, it was correct, and also thanks for the alternate method!

Comment: Can you tell me, what this function does? Why is this correct and his code doesn't work? :)

Comment: e.target makes sure that we are using the anchor tag clicked

Comment: `this` in the question already does that. This answer solves nothing, so I'm not sure why it even got accepted

Answer (score 1):

In your case I wouldn't use the text of the link, as it's possible it may change in the future (ie. you need to translate your website). The better solution is to add custom attribute to links:

```
<div id="my-div">
  <div><a href="#" sectionId="someId1">tag 1</a></div>
  <div><a href="#" sectionId="someId2">tag 2</a></div>
</div>
```

And then put the id of the hidden tag there, so you and up with:

```
$('#my-div a').click(function() {
  var sectionId = $(this).attr('sectionId');
  $('#' + sectionId).show();
  return false; // return false so the browser will not scroll your page
});
```

Comment: `<a>`'s don't have value attribute. ;)

Comment: what do you suggest to do with W3C validation when you add custom attributes ?

Comment: @Umair - if you care about it than upgrade to HTML5 and use data- attribute.

Comment: If you're using HTML5 you could use custom data attributes (data-section-id="someId1").

Comment: Thanks Jakub, but because I'm using a CMS, there are issues with this solution that I don't want to get into, but I think your idea is great for other situations.

Comment: @Jakub HTML 5 is not fully adapted by the web yet!

Answer (score -2):

$('#my-div a') is ambiguous.

It goes to read all the a tags within '#my-div'

U need to specify which of the 2 tags is clicked..